# Get facebook access token with spring social FacebookConnectionFactory

Tags: java, facebook, spring, facebook-graph-api, spring-social

I am trying to implement a Facebook Connection using Spring Social, based on this example(from spring social manual):

```
FacebookConnectionFactory connectionFactory = 
    new FacebookConnectionFactory("clientId", "clientSecret");
OAuth2Operations oauthOperations = connectionFactory.getOAuthOperations();
OAuth2Parameters params = new OAuth2Parameters();
params.setRedirectUri("https://my-callback-url");
String authorizeUrl = oauthOperations.buildAuthorizeUrl(GrantType.AUTHORIZATION_CODE, params);
response.sendRedirect(authorizeUrl);

// upon receiving the callback from the provider:
AccessGrant accessGrant = oauthOperations.exchangeForAccess(authorizationCode, "https://my-callback-url", null);
Connection<Facebook> connection = connectionFactory.createConnection(accessGrant);
```

My problem is that I don't know what my redirect url should be.My code is this:

```
@RequestMapping("/face")
    public String communicate() {
        FacebookConnectionFactory connectionFactory = 
                new FacebookConnectionFactory(clientId, clientSecret);
            OAuth2Operations oauthOperations = connectionFactory.getOAuthOperations();
            OAuth2Parameters params = new OAuth2Parameters();
                    //this remdirectUri should be another one?
            params.setRedirectUri("http://dev01.spring:8080/spring/face");
            String authorizeUrl = oauthOperations.buildAuthorizeUrl(GrantType.AUTHORIZATION_CODE, params);
            System.out.println(authorizeUrl);
            //return "redirect:"+authorizeUrl;

            // upon receiving the callback from the provider:
            //AccessGrant accessGrant = oauthOperations.exchangeForAccess(authorizationCode, "https://my-callback-url", null);
            //Connection<Facebook> connection = connectionFactory.createConnection(accessGrant);
    }
```

My authorizeUrl is like this(from System.out line):
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=myId&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdev01.spring%3A8080%2Fspring%2Fface

If i uncomment the line where I continue the Oauth flow redirecting to this authorizeUrl, i'm getting the following error: This webpage has a redirect loop.
So my question is, what the redirect uri should be.Thank you.

***Very late edit***, in the hopes it helps someone. This is my controller and the method that does the whole Oauth2 dance. I must add that this worked when the question was asked, I have no idea how it behaves now.

```
@Controller
public class FacebookController {

    private static final String clientId = "clientIdHere";              // clientId from facebook app
    private static final String clientSecret = "clientSecret here";     // clientSecret
    private FacebookConnectionFactory connectionFactory;                    // facebookConnectionFactory

    /*
     * If an authorization was given by provider(code) we get an token and bind the api.
     */
    @RequestMapping("/facebook/callback")
    public String authorize(@RequestParam("code") String authorizationCode,Model model) {
        // exchange facebook code with an access token.                                                                 
        AccessGrant accessGrant = connectionFactory.getOAuthOperations().exchangeForAccess(authorizationCode, "http://localhost:8080/testApp/facebook/callback", null); // not that the application was deployed at "http://localhost:8080/testApp"
        // connect to facebook with the given token.
        Connection<Facebook> connection = connectionFactory.createConnection(accessGrant);
        // bind the api
        Facebook facebook = connection.getApi();
        // get user profile informations
        FacebookProfile userProfile = facebook.userOperations().getUserProfile();

        // At this point you have acces to the facebook api.
        // For ex you can get data about the user profile like this

        // create user with facebook's user accounts details.
        User facebookUser = new User(userProfile.getFirstName(),
                userProfile.getLastName(),
                userProfile.getEmail(),
                Role.ROLE_FACEBOOKUSER,
                "socialuser");

        return "redirect:/home";
    }
}
```

Comment: Once you authorize with any OAuth provider after successful authorization they need to know your page where they should redirect. This link should be available on internet.

Comment: How setRedirectURL must be written if I use Spring WebFlow and work in local???

Comment: @RafaelRuizTabares I have edited my question with a piece of working code. Note that the example I added was working at the time the question was posted, I don't know how it works now. I hope it helps you.